# DATETIME/INTERVAL datatype conversion error

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

i'm trying to load data in oracle but get subject mentioned error in my log the format of date in my data is like (2014.08.08 04:27:24) without brackets and the my DDL where I create table is 
simple

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
   ("registerdate" TIMESTAMP (0)
    "other files")
```

and I mentioned the same mask in my control file as

```
registerdate timestamp 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Thanks for help
regards

Comment: Can you try inserting manually using INSERT statement? Just execute     INSERT INTO tablename select to_timestamp('2014.08.08 04:27:24','YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual

Comment: What value is in the .bad file? If you think that looks OK can you show the whole control file, table definition, and that a rejected record? Sounds like you have an entry in the wrong format though.

Comment: Ideally along with the rejected record, the associated error would be ORA-26041: DATETIME/INTERVAL datatype conversion error

Comment: When I do (select to_timestamp('2014.08.08 04:27:24','YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual ) I get result of (08-AUG-14 04.27.24.000000000 AM) is that the issue?

Answer (score 1):

How about the `SQL` Style format below.

```
registerdate TO_TIMESTAMP(TRIM(:registerdate),'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')
             NULLIF registerdate =BLANKS
```